# How to make an array accept only numbers in c programming?

Tags: c

So my task is to make an array that accepts 10  characters. If the characters entered by the user are greater than 10, then an error is dispayed. If the 10 characters entered contain a letter, it displays another error.
Therefore, the array can only have 10 numbers and nothing else, if the numbers entered are less or more than 10, error is displayed as well as if there are letters in the array.

My code accepts both numbers and letters, as i cannot figure out how to display error when letters are entered.

```
void getTenDigitPhone(char telNum[])
{
    int i;
    int z = 1;

    do
    {
        scanf("%s", telNum);
        if (strlen(telNum) != 10)
        {
            printf("Enter a 10-digit phone number: ");
            z = 1;
        }
        else if (strlen(telNum) == 10)
        {
            return telNum;
        }
    } while (z == 1);
}
```

Comment: can you include your code in text form instead of a photo?

Comment: Get the "number" as a string. Check the length of the string ([`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen)). Iterate over the string checking that all characters are digits ([`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit)).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check that `telNum` contains only digits:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    if (!isdigit(telNum[i])) {
        // handle error because a non-digit was found.
    }
```

I'm not going to do your homework for you but this should give you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `isdigit(x)`.

This returns true (non-zero) if `x` is a digit and returns false (zero) if not.

You have to check digit by digit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give an answer because you have posted your current code as your effort. As other answers you should use `isdigit(x)` function.

```
...
else if (strlen(telNum) == 10)
{
    int i;
    char err = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (!isdigit(telNum[i])) {
             // Your error here
             printf("Non-digit character found");
             err = 1;
             break;
        }
    }
    if (err == 0) {
        return telNum;
    }
}
...
```